# How can I make an account_linking with botbuilder Cards

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, azure-bot-service

How can I can I make an account linking after the user authentication to a site from a messenger bot developed using **Microsoft azure** **botbuilder 4.9.0** , **node.js**?

Apparently **signinCard** does not have the account_linking button type, so I thought about using channeldata (bot to user action) to get the Authorization/authentication token but it does not work, I'm trying **oauth** now, Any other suggestions?

Here is the **messenger account_linking** documentation that I'm working with, but apparently not compatible with botbuilder 4.9.3 : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/account-linking

Here is the microsoft signinCards documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/signincard?view=botbuilder-ts-3.0

```js
// the signin button code     
const reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
const card = CardFactory.signinCard('Sign in/Register', 'https://xxxxxx/xxx/account/login?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx', 'To continue, sign in to your account!');
reply.attachments = [card];
await context.sendActivity(reply);
```

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5998

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would like to help, but I need some more information. I see that you're using the facebook-messenger-bot and azure-bot-service tags, so are we to assume you're using the Facebook Messenger channel in ABS? What are you trying to do with channelData, and are you talking about channelData in user-to-bot or bot-to-user activities? What is sourceEvent? What is account_linking? Can you post screenshots and link to any documentation or samples that you're following? Please edit your question to include the needed information rather than putting it in comments.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I edited the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes account_linking different from the normal third-party OAuth flow in the Bot Framework? For all we know, signin actions already get converted to account_linking actions automatically. Have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication

Comment: Are you still working on this?